# Merge two or more objects with the same value in list

Tags: python, python-itertools

I would like to merge two or more objects in the list with the same `moment`enum value and add the `value` to ourselves. Will be better if I write an example:

**Input:**

```
[Credit(value=111, moment=<CreditMoment.APP: 'APP'>), Credit(fee_value=222, moment=<CreditMoment.APP: 'APP'>), Credit(value=444, moment=<CreditMoment.OFFER: 'OFFER'>)]
```

**Expected result:**

```
[Credit(value=333, moment=<CreditMoment.APP: 'APP'>), Credit(value=444, moment=<CreditMoment.OFFER: 'OFFER'>)]
```

As you can see now the expected list has 2 elements which first element has combined `value=333`

The elements came from this class:

```
class CreditMoment(str, AutoNameEnum):
    APP= auto()
    OFFER = auto()
    COMPLETION = auto()
```

Comment: may I ask where did you get that items from your list?

Comment: Yea sure, the objects came from this class:
```
class CreditMoment(str, AutoNameEnum):
    APP= auto()
    OFFER = auto()
```

Comment: Meh.. I can't format it properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will help.

```
dic = {}
for credit in lis:
    # Will create a dict that willh have moment value as key and sum all the values
    dic[credit.moment.value] = dic.get(credit.moment.value, 0) + credit.value

# Now recreate the list

[Credit(value=v, moment=x) for x,v in dic.items()]
```